# Nested JSON parsing using Snowflake SQL

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a problem parsing a certain nested JSON structure in Snowflake. The problem here is the usage of special characters like @ and # for example for some of the elements. Those characters prevents me from using simple dot notation when trying to access some of the elements without resourcing to a really complicated queries utilizing joins and where clauses on the flattened parts of the structure. Here's an example of how the JSON file looks like:

```
{
  "ContractTerm": [
    {
      "@ID": 123123,
      "CodeTermTypeID": {
        "#text": "some_text 123123"
      },
      "ContractID": {
        "#text": "other_text 123123",
        "@href": "/businessObject/123123",
        "@ID": 123123
      },
      "ContractTermID": 123123
    },
    {
      "@ID": 234234,
      "CodeTermStatusID": {
        "#text": "some_text_again 234234"
      },
      "CodeTermTypeID": {
        "#text": "some_text 234234"
      },
      "ContractID": {
        "#text": "some_other_text 234234",
        "@href": "/businessObject/234234",
        "@lxID": 234234
      },
      "ContractTermID": 234234
    },
    {
      "@lD": 345345,
      "CodeTermTypeID": {
        "#text": "another_text 345345"
      },
      "ContractID": {
        "#text": "another_text 345345",
        "@href": "/businessObject/345345",
        "@lxID": 345345
      },
      "ContractTermID": 345345
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to get those elements starting with @ and # like using some escape characters or something similar in SQL code?

Comment: Please show us your current query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use quotes around the attributes with special characters.  For example:

```
WITH x as (
SELECT parse_json('{
  "ContractTerm": [
    {
      "@ID": 123123,
      "CodeTermTypeID": {
        "#text": "some_text 123123"
      },
      "ContractID": {
        "#text": "other_text 123123",
        "@href": "/businessObject/123123",
        "@ID": 123123
      },
      "ContractTermID": 123123
    },
    {
      "@ID": 234234,
      "CodeTermStatusID": {
        "#text": "some_text_again 234234"
      },
      "CodeTermTypeID": {
        "#text": "some_text 234234"
      },
      "ContractID": {
        "#text": "some_other_text 234234",
        "@href": "/businessObject/234234",
        "@lxID": 234234
      },
      "ContractTermID": 234234
    },
    {
      "@lD": 345345,
      "CodeTermTypeID": {
        "#text": "another_text 345345"
      },
      "ContractID": {
        "#text": "another_text 345345",
        "@href": "/businessObject/345345",
        "@lxID": 345345
      },
      "ContractTermID": 345345
    }
  ]
}') as var)
SELECT y.value:"@ID"
FROM x,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input=>x.var:ContractTerm) y
```

Comment: Thanks for help! It works, however when I'm trying to use the below query all I get are NULL value. It seems like I can't go down a level below using the "@ID"? SELECT y.value:"@ID"
,z.value:"@ID"
FROM x,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input=>x.var:ContractTerm) y,
lateral flatten(input=>y.value:ContractID) z;

Comment: Under ContractID is "@lxID" not "@ID".  Could that be the issue?  When you make reference to an attribute that isn't there, you'll always get a NULL.

Comment: OK - thank you again! I corrected it and it works perfectly now! Too bad it doesn't work with COPY INTO unfortunately as it's "too complicated"...